# How can I count how many elements are in an ICollection in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following class in my model:

```
public class Notebook : TableServiceEntity
{
    public string NotebookLinksJSON { get; set; }

    public string NotebookLinksCount {
        get {
            var a = NotebookLinksJSON.FromJSONString<Notebook.Link>().Details;
            var b = a.Count();
            return NotebookLinksJSON.FromJSONString<Notebook.Link>().Details.Count();
        }
    }

    public class Link
    {
        public Link() {
            _details = new List<Detail>();
        }
        public IList<Detail> Details { 
            get { return _details; } 
        }

        private List<Detail> _details = new List<Detail>();

        public class Detail
        {
            public string L { get; set; }
            public string R { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

What I want is to have a property NotebookLinksCount that will return the number of details in the NotebookLinksJSON string.

The datatypes of the vars are as follows:

```
var a = NotebookLinksJSON.FromJSONString<Notebook.Link>().Details;
var b = a.Count();

a is an interface System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>
b is ?? <<< nothing shows when I try to find out what type it is
```

When I build I get the following error:

```
Error   3   Non-invocable member 
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<S.Storage.Models.Notebook.Link.Detail>.Count' 
cannot be used like a method.
```

Can someone help me with some advice as to how I can get the count of NotebookLinks? Also if NotebookLinksJSON is a null then I would like the count to return a zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Count` is a property. Remove the `()` and call it like:

```
NotebookLinksJSON.FromJSONString<Notebook.Link>().Details.Count;
```

**Edit:**
Answering a question from @Melissa in the comments: To make it return null in the event that the `NotebookLinksJSON` object is null, you need a null check.

```
public int NotebookLinksCount {
    get {
        return (NotebookLinksJSON != null) ?
            NotebookLinksJSON.FromJSONString<Notebook.Link>().Details.Count :
            0;
    }
}
```

And I recommend changing your NotebookLinksCount property to return an int. Though if you really need a string, you can change it to be that.

```
public string NotebookLinksCount {
    get {
        return (NotebookLinksJSON != null) ?
            NotebookLinksJSON.FromJSONString<Notebook.Link>().Details.Count.ToString() :
            "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Count() exists as well, as a LINQ extension method.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels, I think she is trying to use System.Linq.Enumerable.Count() extension method on a non-generic collection, so it can still be a method. `NotebookLinksJSON.FromJSONString<Notebook.Link>().Details.OfType<Notebook.Link>().Count()` would be the Linq working code I believe

Comment: Thanks. How could I deal with the situation where there are no details. For the case where the field NotebookLinksJSON is a null then I would like the count to return a zero.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels: It exists if she has referenced the `System.Linq` namespace in a using statement, but it also collides and using the property here would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `return NotebookLinksJSON.FromJSONString<Notebook.Link>().Details.Count;`.

You don't need to call the `Extension` method here

Comment: Thanks. How could I deal with the situation where there are no details. For the case where the field NotebookLinksJSON is a null then I would like the count to return a zero.

Comment: You have to `null` check it then! Even if you have used the extension method you would have an exception anyway. So better to check for `null` first